# Maximum number of beep repeats in the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, beep-code

What is the maximum number of `beep` repeats that we can pass to the `-r` flag in the terminal?

I'm not seeing anything in the documentation at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/beep.1.html.

Comment: Chances are it will be one of max 32bit, 64bit, signed or unsigned. Why not just test? It's not difficult. Or just look at the source. Indeed, looking at the source, it is an unsigned 32bit, so 2 ^ 32 - 1. Really not difficult to find.